# Ternary Operator in jQuery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ternary-operator

I'm using a jQuery function to build an html table based on some json I have available.  I use a `for loop` to build tables for each entry in my json.  In one case I want to check the value of the json element to see if it has a value.  If so I want to build an html link with an image.  I thought using a ternary statement would be the cleanest by checking for the value using `.isEmptyObject()` function.  When I do it doesn't build as expected and acts like it just gives up on that line all together.  Here's what I've tried.

```
    '<td> ' 
        + (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(json[i].pdf_files)) ? 
          ' <a href="http://site.example/assets/_images/products/pdf/' + 
          json[i].pdf_files + '" target="_blank"> <img src="img/pdf-32.png" alt="pdf" />&nbsp;Spec Sheet</a>'  : '' + 
   ' </td>'  + //continue with appending rest of table
```

If I just do this it works:

```
'<td> ' + ' <a href="http://site.example/assets/_images/products/pdf/' + json[i].pdf_files + '" target="_blank"> <img src="img/pdf-32.png" alt="pdf" />&nbsp;Spec Sheet</a> </td>' +
```

Comment: well you do not put the closing td with it.... better formatting might show that easier.

Comment: As epascarello says, `</td>` on the `?` portion is missing, or you need to do `: ''`

Comment: Apologies... I didn't paste my code correctly.  Fixed above.  The </td> is there

Comment: so add parenthesis around it so it knows where the ternary operator ends.

Comment: Thats it! It was the parenthesis.  Working! If you add an answer I'll gladly accept.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add parenthesis around the entire ternary operator so it know where to stop.

```
'<td> ' + ( x ? 'foo' : 'bar' ) + '</td>'
```